# Load/Save GUI game -- NoSuchElementException error

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm extremely new to using GUIs and JPanel with Java. Right now I am working on a game that can be saved and loaded. When saved, it takes a JArray and depending on whether nothing is at a place or a certain picture, saves `0s, 1s, and 2s` to a file. When loading it looks at the `0s, 1s, and 2s` and replaces them at the corresponding spot (in a for-loop) with pictures or nothing.

When I load my game it hardly loads and errors out with "`NoSuchElementException`." Here is my load:

```
 public void loadGame() throws FileNotFoundException{

        String fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your file's name?") + ".txt";
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));
         playerOne = reader.next();
         playerTwo = reader.next();
         counter = reader.nextInt();
        for (int i = 1; i < grid_height-1; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= grid_width-1; j++) {

                    if(reader.nextInt() == 1){game[i][j].setIcon(p1);}
                    if(reader.nextInt() == 2){game[i][j].setIcon(p2);} 
                    else if(reader.nextInt() == 0){game[i][j].setIcon(null); } } } 

    reader.close(); 
} 

    }
```

And if needed, my save:

```
        public void saveGame() throws FileNotFoundException{
        String fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What will you name your file?") + ".txt";
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fileName);
        out.println(playerOne);
        out.println(playerTwo);
        out.println(counter);
        for (int i = 1; i < grid_height-1; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= grid_width-1; j++) {
                if(game[i][j].getIcon() == null){out.println(0); }
                else if(game[i][j].getIcon() == p1){out.println(1);}
                else if(game[i][j].getIcon() == p2){out.println(2); }
            }
        }
        out.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saved successfully!", "Saved", 
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated. The error usually strikes at if(reader.nextInt() == #) in the code. I've made sure in the file that there IS an integer next, too.

Comment: Something is fishy with your i and j loops (`<` vs `<=`) and you should use  `hasNextInt()` on `Scanner`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save the return value of [nextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) properly and use it for comparison.

```
public void loadGame() throws FileNotFoundException{

       //your code here ........
        for (int i = 1; i < grid_height-1; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= grid_width-1; j++) {
                    if(reader.hasNext()){
                         int next = reader.nextInt(); //save the return value and use it for comparision

                         if (next == 1){game[i][j].setIcon(p1);}
                         if (next  == 2){game[i][j].setIcon(p2);} 
                         else if(next  == 0){game[i][j].setIcon(null);
                    } //close the if loop
        //rest of your code here .......
```